# UK GiftAid Addresses not populating

Tags: gift-aid-extension

After importing all Gift Aid Contacts the address field in the declaration isn't being auto populated which leads to batch errors, is there a simple fix? if I open the declaration and instantly save it it is populated

Comment: Assuming you have imported the declarations as  well as the contacts - this is a limitation of how it works in my experience.  The simple fix is to update the declarations with some SQL as far as I'm aware.